# Add HttpClientHandler to HttpClient global static variable

Tags: c#

could someone help me.
How I can add my HttpClientHanlder to my HttpClient Global variable?
someone said that I'm doing wrong for always making a new httpclient for every request.

If i tried like this:

```
   //global variable
   // the handler isn't working
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(addHandlers());
    
        private static HttpClientHandler addHandlers()
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseProxy = Proxy.IsUseProxy ? true : false,
                Proxy = Proxy.IsUseProxy ? new WebProxy($"{Proxy.ProxyHost}:{Proxy.ProxyPort}") : null,
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; },
                // SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls
            };
        }
```

and here where I do my request

```
   public static async Task<JsonDocument> ParseJsonData(string api, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        client = new HttpClient(addHandlers()); //this is might my wrong doing? re-creating every request.
        var uri = new Uri(api, UriKind.Absolute);
      
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
        {
           /// etc..
        }
    }
```

UPDATE FIXED:

```
private static HttpClientHandler addHandlers = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseProxy = Proxy.UseProxy,
        Proxy = Proxy.UseProxy ? new WebProxy($"{Proxy.ProxyHost}:{Proxy.ProxyPort}") : null,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
    };

    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(addHandlers);
```

Comment: You forgot to name and use the `static HttpClient`

Comment: `private static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = Proxy.IsUseProxy, etc. };`

Comment: Oh wait. let me try it.

Comment: the handler is throwing an error. here's what I've tried.
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(addHandlers);

        private static HttpClientHandler addHandlers = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseProxy = etc..
        };

Comment: @Flutterish yeah. it's just typo :)

Comment: Sorry it worked. I have to put my handler above the httpclient

Comment: Field initializers are executed in textual order. So `client` must be initialized after `handlers`

Comment: @AluanHaddad could you post the solution from my update. so that I can mark your answer

Comment: @AluanHaddad yeah that's what I did already :)

Comment: What is `IsUseProxy`? That is a weird name and if it is boolean, the ternary operator makes no sense. I don't want to write an answer that perpetuates it :-p

Comment: @AluanHaddad it's a boolean from my proxy class. I just separated my proxy input/call so that I have a choice from my UI either use proxy or not.

Comment: The separation is fine but the usage and naming is bad. It should be named `UseProxy` because "use" already connotes a boolean meaning and "is" confuses that. Also you shouldn't have logic like  `condition ? true : false` because it means `condition`

Comment: haha alright I'll just gonna change the name.

Comment: my only little problem is adding the defaultrequestheaders from httclient. But i'm trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

`private static HttpClient = new HttpClient(addHandlers());`

This is not valid code. You need to actually give a name to your static field:

`private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(addHandlers());`